# Calling table function from procedure (pl sql)

Tags: function, plsql, procedure

I am having big trouble calling a function that returns a table from my procedure. I believe there is something wrong with my declaration so its not compiling. Here is my code.. the developer underlines with red the **SELECT "D_ID"**  and **from table "(IREL_FN (X))";** . And here is my code.

```
CREATE OR replace PROCEDURE Irrelevant_skata (x NUMBER)
AS
  d_id T_ID_TABLE;
BEGIN
  DECLARE
  TYPE yo_table
IS
  TABLE OF YO_TABLE;
  YO_TABLE "(IREL_FN (X))"%TYPE;
  id                 NUMBER;
BEGIN
  SELECT "D_ID"
  INTO   yo_table
  FROM   TABLE "(IREL_FN (X))";

EXCEPTION
WHEN no_data_found THEN
  dbms_output.Put_line('NO DATA FOUND');
END;
END irrelevant_skata;
```

And the function

```
CREATE OR replace FUNCTION Irel_fn (x IN NUMBER)
RETURN T_ID_TABLE
AS
  id T_ID_TABLE;
BEGIN
    BEGIN
        SELECT Cast(MULTISET(SELECT "id"
                             FROM   "somethingcopy"
                             WHERE  "kati" IN (SELECT "auto"
                                               FROM   "ekeino"
                                               WHERE  "id" = x)) AS T_ID_TABLE)
        INTO   id
        FROM   dual;

        RETURN id;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN no_data_found THEN
          dbms_output.Put_line('null');
    END;
END irel_fn;
```

Comment: `bob "(IREL_FN (X))"%TYPE;`  and `TABLE "(IREL_FN (X))";` are declared/used incorrectly.

Comment: Can you please tell me the correct way?

Comment: @Sathya I really need the answer my friend.. My boss is pressing me.. plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create or replace
PROCEDURE IRRELEVANT_SKATA (INSID IN NUMBER) AS ID T_ID_TABLE ;
BEGIN
      DECLARE
          YO_TABLE T_ID_TABLE;
      BEGIN
          select ID 
          into YO_TABLE
          from table(IREL_FN(INSID));
      EXCEPTION
          WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN dbms_output.put_line('NO DATA FOUND');      
      END;
END IRRELEVANT_TWEET;



<-----------------------------FUNCTION---------------------------------->

create or replace
FUNCTION IREL_FN ( D_ID IN NUMBER ) RETURN T_ID_TABLE AS 
ID T_ID_TABLE;
BEGIN      
BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(
    MULTISET(
    SELECT "Id"
    FROM "SOMETHINGCOPY"
    WHERE "KATI" = (SELECT "EKEINO" FROM "AUTO" WHERE "Id"=D_ID)
    INTO ID
    FROM DUAL;
return ID;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN dbms_output.put_line('null');    
END;

END IREL_FN;
```

I hope I helped :)

Comment: you are the most correct.. although  I have already done it.. :)  Thank you for the concern

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to answer without knowing what you're trying to do.

```
YO_TABLE "(IREL_FN (X))"%TYPE;
```

This doesn't make any sense. You can't declare a variable to be `%type` of a function. Looking up at YO_TABLE declaration, you write

```
  DECLARE
  TYPE yo_table
IS
  TABLE OF YO_TABLE;
```

Huh? table declaration is table of same variable you're declaring?

---

And this:

```
  SELECT "D_ID"
  INTO   yo_table
  FROM   TABLE "(IREL_FN (X))";
```

You don't need quotes when casting table, and the `x` in IREL_FN (X) is a formal parameter, you need to replace it with the actual value what you need to pass

Comment: DECLARE
     Yo_TABLE as T_ID_TABLE
     ID number;
BEGIN
      select * into YO_TABLE from table(IREL_FN(X)); Now I have it like this.. and again not compiling.. i want to just simply call the table function from the procedure

Comment: Like I said, you're calling `IREL_FN(X))`. X is a formal argument, not an actual argument. You need replace value of 'x' with what you need to pass

Comment: before this step.. The function wasnt returning a table.. but a single value.. and I hadnt any problem calling the function from the procedure and compiling was fine.. without having any problem with the X .. now that the function returns table should I write something more or different for X?

Comment: X is an Id that the user gives to the procedure and which calls the function which depending of this X will make a table .... for example select * from table(IREL_FN(959217)); works fine .. it returns me the table  l want... my problem is that i cant compile the procedure

Comment: it's not compiling because `DECLARE Yo_TABLE as T_ID_TABLE ID number;` is incorrect. Please see [ask], then [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) a new question properly stating what you want to do and all declarations. I suspect [this is a xy problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/133693)

Comment: I am new to this.. and I think I do very stupid mistakes moreover I cant understand much of what you say.. So an example of how You would declaring and calling a tabled function from a procedure would be really helpful.. (and also thanks a lot for your time already)

Comment: See [René's](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/plsql/coll/return_table.html) example for what you're trying to do

Comment: that example doesnt use-call the function into a procedure. the problem is in my procedure not in my function

Comment: It compiled.. thanks for your time Sathya!! It was the X !! you were right!!! :D :D

Answer (score 0):

I am answering to your question marked as duplicate (the problem with exact fetch).
I rewrote your code in the following way, hope it helps. I makes the Irel_fn to be a pipelined function, however you can still write Cast multiset if you like , however you  need to use type constructor as well.

```
create table auto(id number)
```

this table is instead of your source "AUTO" (so I could compile it).

```
create or replace type t_id as object (id number);
/
Create or replace type t_id_table is table of t_id;
/
create or replace FUNCTION Irel_fn (x IN NUMBER) RETURN T_ID_TABLE PIPELINED
as
BEGIN
 for rec in (select id from auto where id=x)
loop
 Pipe row (t_id(rec.id));
end loop;
return;
end;  
/
create or replace procedure Irrelevant_skata (insid in NUMBER) is
bob t_id_table;
BEGIN      
  select t_id(id) bulk collect into bob from table(irel_fn(insid)); 
END;
```

Comment: really thank you Mina.. I did it yesterday with another way.. but your solution is very educating . I will keep it in my notes. Again.. thank you!